# error in .groupby and .agg when using a tuple column

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I'm having trouble using
    .groupby
and
    .agg
using a tuple column

here is the .info()

```
account_aggregates.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9713 entries, 0 to 9712
Data columns (total 14 columns):
NATIVEACCOUNTKEY           9713 non-null int64
(POLL, sum)              9713 non-null int64
num_cancellations          8 non-null float64
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
session_deciles2_grouped = account_aggregates.groupby(('POLL','sum'))
```

and this:

```
session_deciles22=session_deciles2_grouped[('POLL','sum')].agg(['mean','count'])
```

but the columns aren't being recognized - I keep getting a key error.

Comment: `account_aggregates.groupby([('POLL','sum'),])` works? `account_aggregates.groupby(('POLL','sum'))` sounds like there is a column `POLL` and there is a column `sum` and groupby should use both of them as keys.

Comment: yep.   account_aggregates.groupby([('POLL','sum'),]) does indeed work.  why do i need to have [ ] around my tuple (which need ( ) ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`account_aggregates.groupby([('POLL','sum'),])` would be required here.

The reason `account_aggregates.groupby(('POLL','sum'))` won't work is because `('POLL','sum')` is a collection, and `groupby` reads this as there are a column called `POLL` and there is a column called `sum`, and use both columns to do a groupby operation.

when we put `('POLL','sum')` in a list, it means to groupby by a column named `('POLL','sum')`.

Therefore, `account_aggregates.groupby([('POLL','sum'),])` or `account_aggregates.groupby((('POLL','sum'),))` will work.